# Need to parse using regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want to parse this string `"{"name":"template","id":100}"` and take the string `"template"` using regular Expression.

Note: It is a JSON, but my scenario is to parse as a string. Please provide some solution through regular Expression

Comment: This looks like the [data format JSON](http://json.org/). If so, can’t you use a proper JSON parser?

Comment: Which language? Which regex dialect? This seems to be JSON, so why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: `/(template)/`. Just kidding... I fully agree with @Gumbo.

Comment: That brings back flashes from all those "parse HTML with regex" questions :-(

Comment: If you use java, it is really simple and readible to use split(":") and split(",").
String [] parsed = linea.split(":");
parsed[1] = parsed.split(",");

And you have at parsed[0] "template". If you want something more sophisticated you can use a single regular expression, but that's more tricky and perl-demanding, hehe

Comment: Why can't you use a JSON parser? Is it homework?

Comment: Am using jmeter, I want to parse this response string and give it as input to another request.

Answer (score 0):

/{"name":"(.*?)","/

It's captured in group 1.